# $.scrollTo to div doesn't work with my current JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I have tried to add a scrollTo function to my actual JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
        $('#me').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

It just basically display the hidden div under the actual text

What I would like to do is it should jump right away to div

---

Js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3zahL1qv/

---

What I tried to do is adding `$.scrollTo($('#me'), 500);`, but for some reason it does nothing but just break my current JS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just add $(window).scrollTop(500); in your code. Here is a working example-http://jsfiddle.net/3zahL1qv/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
        $('#me').stop().slideToggle(500);
        $(window).scrollTop(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Better way to do it as follow:

```
$(function() {
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('#me').stop().slideToggle(500);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#me").position()["top"]}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

});

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3zahL1qv/13/

Comment: hey thanks, but I would like to make a slow-ish scroll effect to jump directly to that certain div, is that possible with the current code?

Comment: I cant see what you have changed, but It still doesn't work the way I want it, but thanks anyway

Comment: Hi, I messed up a little in previous comment. Please give this one a shot, It would be perfect for you. http://jsfiddle.net/3zahL1qv/13/